# Mass assignment is not restricted using attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting `Mass assignment is not restricted using attr_accessible`

How can I fix this?

Comment: try adding 
 `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`  line in  /config/application.rb  in /config/application.rb file.

Comment: Check this:http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/mass_assignment/

Answer (score 1):

In a default rails-3.x application you will see the following lines in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
# Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
# This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
# in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
# parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
# config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

By default Rails allows you to assign any hash to model attributes.

`This is not a bug in rails. It's just a bit of functionality that makes it quite easy to stab yourself in the face.`

One way is to comment above line which will force you to explicitly whitelist or blacklist attributes of every model.
The second way is to directly use [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) or [attr_protected](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_protected/class) in models and restrict mass_assignment. (I usually go with the second).

More details here: http://happybearsoftware.com/how-i-avoid-the-rails-mass-assignment-security-mistake.html